# How to use Action Creators in Redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I want change the value of field 'Buffer' in my redux-form 'payForm' so
in a dispacth i want use relative action creator

```
import {  actions } from 'react-redux-form'
....
store.dispatch(actions.change('payForm','Buffer', bufferValue);
```

doesn't work, fail silently.

Help !!!

Answer (score 7):

if you want to change value of a particular registered fields then you can follow this approach....

```
import { change } from 'redux-form';
```

import action creator change...
and then you can dispatch change action as..

```
store.dispatch(change('payForm', 'Buffer', bufferValue));
```

for more refer redux-form documentation 
https://redux-form.com/7.2.0/docs/api/actioncreators.md/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `change` from your `props` which will fire the corresponding action, see [here](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/docs/api/props.md/)

So if you have a `Field`

```
<Field name="Buffer" component="input" />
```

inside your form component, you can change it by simply call

```
this.props.change("Buffer", bufferValue);
```

This will in turn call the proper action creator. See [this working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/04p44oj4rn)